# Ubuntu miner worm randomly creating executables and consuming CPU

Tags: ubuntu

My Ubuntu server was infected with a miner worm: https://medium.com/@Alibaba_Cloud/8220-mining-group-now-uses-rootkit-to-hide-its-miners-15d6c571cdb3

Which I proceeded to clean up following the guidelines mentioned here:
https://www.domoticz.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=28329#p217121

That took care of most of it, but there's still a process lounging on my "top -c", consuming high CPU resources.

I did "ps -p ", found the process name, removed the executable from the /tmp directory, and killed the process.

However, another process pops up in its place a few seconds later with a different name, and a different executable in the /tmp folder. It started with ib_addr, then vxfs, then something else, and now it's just random numbers like "1521626697".

How do I get rid of this worm?

Comment: Nuke the system from orbit. Its the only way to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly? Back up the system - dump any databases, dump a package list, and rsync over anything important. Shut down the system - you cannot be *totally* sure the system is clean.

A rootkit essentially is designed to modify system files and you can never really be sure its gone on a running system.

Run an AV scan on the files you rsynced over - you *will* find some stuff that's picked up and that should give you a clear idea of what's wrong.

*Reinstall* a fresh copy of ubuntu. Turn off SSH root logins, set things up so you can *only* do key based auth, and optionally set up something like fail2ban.

Reinstall your software, restore the DBs and so on.

That's to say the only sure way to get rid of a worm is to nuke the system from orbit.

Comment: Or restore from the last *known safe* copy, and import data *carefully* from the infected machine (e.g. as saved zip files, not directly).